# Setting auto heal for azure web app using terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to setup auto heal settings for azure web app using terraform

what have i tried ?

- i am using [windows_web_app](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/windows_web_app)
- I have `auto_heal_enabled`

How can I figure out a reference example to setup triggers and actions for the `auto_heal_settings` mentioned in the documentation [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/windows_web_app#action)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out an example for auto-heal by adding auto heal settings manually using the azure portal and then running `terraform plan` which showed me the exact synatax of the `auto_heal_settings` the plan was going to remove.

This setting shows configuration to recycle your web app when either

- 5000 requests to /HealthCheck throw 500 in 5 min (300 seconds)
- 5000 requests to /Get throw 500 in 5 min (300 seconds)

^ might not be the right settings for your application in production,  however the strategy of figuring out settings can be applied to all scenarios supported by this feature

```
  - auto_heal_setting {
              - action {
                  - action_type                    = "Recycle" -> null
                  - minimum_process_execution_time = "00:00:00" -> null
                }

              - trigger {
                  - private_memory_kb = 0 -> null

                  - status_code {
                      - count             = 5000 -> null
                      - interval          = "00:05:00" -> null
                      - path              = "/HealtCheck" -> null
                      - status_code_range = "500" -> null
                      - sub_status        = 0 -> null
                    }
                  - status_code {
                      - count             = 6000 -> null
                      - interval          = "00:05:00" -> null
                      - path              = "/Get" -> null
                      - status_code_range = "500" -> null
                      - sub_status        = 0 -> null
                    }
                }
```